# Query by computed property in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, properties, computed-field

How can I query the objects by a computed property:
My Book entity:

```
Book{
    //DB field
    bookID int PK,
    bookName nvarchar,
    artID int FK Article(artID)
    int OriginalPrice;
    int Discount;
    //computed
    public int SellPrice{
        get{
            return (OriginalPrice - OriginalPrice*Discount/100 )/500*500;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to select all the book have SellPrice > 5000, but I can't use the SellPrice in LINQ query string or lambda.
I have done some googling and this is seem like good. But can't put my expression to calculate the `SellPrice` in a working way

Comment: Do you work with Sql Server ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, Yes, I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it may help you:

```
var books = (from e in context.Books.AsEnumerable()
            where ((e.OriginalPrice.ToDecimal() - e.OriginalPrice * e.Discount.ToDeciaml() / 100).ToDecimal() / 500 * 500) > 5000
            select e).ToList();
```

Extension Method `ToDecimal` is

```
public static class Extensions
    {            
        public static decimal ToDecimal(this int value)
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use computed expressions without materializing query.
In your case you can explode the expression inside a LINQ query.
I think you are using /500*500 to truncate at 500 units.

```
var books = context.Books.Where(b => ((int)((OriginalPrice - (int)(OriginalPrice * Discount / 100) )/500))*500 > 5000).ToList();
```